# SQL: Cursor vs. Relation

Tags: sql, cursor, relation

In SQL, what is the difference between a cursor and a relation?

I am just learning SQL and trying to figure out what the answer to my question is. Any help and or resources are much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A relation is another name for a table. The language often used in academic research papers etc. is relations and tuples, where as in industry most people refer to these as tables and rows.

A curser is used to retrieve results as described above, but is generally used in a programming environment when you need to do something that the SQL syntax alone is not well suited to e.g. in Oracle you use cursors in pl/sql procedures.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL a cursor is used to retrieve a set of results and then loop through them 1 row at a time.  They are discouraged because you are removing the real strength of SQL, which is set based processing.

I'm not at all certain what you mean when you say "a relation".  I tried Google, and it wasn't much help either.